# Counter in PHP reverted back to 0 after 32,768 (high likely), but just once

Tags: php, file, types, integer

Long time ago I created a website and have a counter in it how much people downloaded my app.
Now I see the counter reverter to a few hundred, while it was above 30,000. I imagine the counter is only 2 bytes.

I don't have much knowledge about PHP, but I guessed the (int) casting causes the problem.

```
<?php
if(!file_exists('Counters/counter_installer.txt')){
  file_put_contents('Counters/counter_installer.txt', '0');
}
if($_GET['click_installer'] == 'yes'){
  file_put_contents('Counters/counter_installer.txt', ((int) file_get_contents('Counters/counter_installer.txt')) + 1);
  header('Location: ' . 'http://www.example.com/Releases/foobar.3.1.0.exe');
  die;
}
```

So what I did was to change `(int)` to `long`, but since long seems not to be valid in PHP the page couldn't be loaded, so I reverted it back.

Than I changed the content of the file (196) to 32964 (=32768 + 196), and found out it started increasing again (when I clicked the download button).

So one time, the counter got back (to 0?) I assume, and I do not have a clue why.

Is it related to the integer / 2 byte value? Or something else?

Comment: Sounds unlikely that this is the problem, a signed integer on a 32-bit system goes up to 2147483647.

Comment: Somehow the problem is solved, but I don't know why it happened in the first place.

Comment: `int` *might* be the problem @MichelKeijzers and while looking for something similar, have found that others have used `intval` instead. I myself can't explain this, but probably if I spend more time on it.

Comment: @jeroen See answer

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Somehow it works now, but still don't know what happened. For me you don't have to spend much time, it's not so important (it's just a hobby site), but I was kind of surprised the value 196 was there while it was around 32,000 some week(s) ago.

Comment: @MichelKeijzers Yeah I know but sometimes I like going the extra mile to *try* and find out the actual reason. I'm glad you found a way to make it run. Pretty odd behaviour though.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I can imagine; it never happened before, since I check it reasonably regular (every few weeks, during the last year). I'm almost sure it's the overflow from 32,768, or otherwise very co-incidental.

Comment: @vivek I don't know who upvoted my answer, since I just added it to mention I don't have the problem anymore (or as you can say, can happen again). I removed my answer and added it into my question instead.

Comment: @MichelKeijzers  Great. Converting to `(int)` shouldn't cause a problem related to overflow. You can see that PHP automatically handles it and pushes it to next numbers. https://3v4l.org/4c7lD Are you sure you never deleted the file previously or did it get deleted through some script?

Comment: @vivek_23 Yes indeed, so guess it was a concurrency problem of some kind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

File-based counters are extremely tricky to get right in multi-user environments and you aren't doing any error checking. The simplest fix would be a proper database of any kind (seriously). If that isn't feasible, you'd need to at least account for concurrency and abort counter update with corrupted data. You may want to check [flock()](https://www.php.net/flock) as starting point.

Comment: Thanks for that script … indeed a proper database I understand is better, but a bit beyond what it gains for me (just interested in the number, no commercial reason or anything important to my hobby project).

Comment: I understand that. I just wanted to emphasise that simple solutions are sometimes more difficult to create because you need to write everything from scratch by yourself.

Comment: True, but the flock() function seems a major improvement already.